# Fetch Parameters from arg1:value/arg2:value2

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like:-

```
object_id:56/object:display/role:test
```

I want to fetch all params from string like

> $object_id = 56 and $object = display and so on...

Tried http://php.net/EXPLODE#99167

this gave me an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => object_id
            [1] => 56
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => object
            [1] => display
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => role
            [1] => test
        )

)
```

I want them as

> $object_id = 56
>   $object = display

Comment: hint: [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE)

Comment: Comments from php.net could be useful: http://php.net/EXPLODE#99167

Comment: Hi @sectus tried this one but it is giving an array, i want them to variables i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just explode them, first by `/` forward slashes, then explode again the exploded pieces by `:` colon:

```
$string = 'object_id:56/object:display/role:test';
foreach(explode('/', $string) as $val1) {
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $val1);
    $$key = $val;
}

echo $object_id , '<br/>', $object , '<br/>', $role;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tr8PXo)